# Google Custom Search: Issues retrieving promotions using file type exclusion in query

Tags: file-type, google-custom-search

I'm having issues retrieving promotions when using file type exclusion in the query. I have tested with no file type exclusions in the query, and then I get my promotions in addition to a lot of results that I do not want.

Is there a workaround for this? Is it possible to set the file exclusion in the custom search engine console?

You can see how I have used the file type exclusion [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#wsSpecialQueryTerms)

**EDIT: Using param as_eq**

I've also tried the param as_eq, e.g. &as_eq=filetype%3Apdf

Still same result!?